# CSS button unset $_POST

Tags: php, html, css, post

I downloaded a html with a CSS template. In the login form(where was initially placed the blue-button css works. I copied the same html code for button into another area and when I click on it doesn't work.

CSS

```
.blue-button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: solid 1px #6d8794;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px #6d8794;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    behavior: url(css/PIE.php);
}

.blue-button span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: solid 1px #6d8794;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px #a6bcc8;
    background: #85a3b3 url("../images/blue-button-stripes.gif") repeat-x left top;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 26px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    behavior: url(css/PIE.php);
}

.blue-button a, .blue-button input {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    height: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #687b85;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
}

.blue-button:hover a, .blue-button:hover input {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

PHP

```
public function ShowLoginPanel()
{    

 $this->LoginContent=
 '  <div class="column-1-3">
        <div class="white-box">

            <div class="box-content fixed-height">
                <form action="" method="post" class="contact-form">
                    <div>
                            <span class="blue-button"><span><input type="submit" value="SEND &raquo;" /></span></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="val" value="checkin">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/end .column-1-3 --> ';     

}
```

When I click the button, the $_POST["val"] is set but when I use the same code in another unit(instance registration.php)

```
     <div class="icon"><img src="images/register.png" alt="" /></div>
     <input type="hidden" name="val" value="registration">';
```

**the $_POST["val"]  is unset and it doesn't do anything.**

You can access my page from here http://tinyurl.com/pkw5wly In order to make a summary, my question is why in the loggin div the button works but in the registration div it doesn't work

Comment: This wouldn't be a CSS issue. Your `<form>` has no `action` in the code posted. Where is the `action` set?

Comment: You can access the page.

Comment: @LoganMurphy `post` would be the method. `action` would be the page you want the form to hit.

Comment: @Chris Sobolewski Yeah you are right. @user558126 Does your form have `method="post"`?

Comment: Can you access the page? http://tinyurl.com/pkw5wly

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it  It's likely nobody will click your link. The example of your problem should be self contained.

Comment: I'm certainly not clicking on a tinyurl.com link. Post the relevant stuff to jsfiddle or something.

Comment: I have the guts! I clicked on the link! And, oh well, it's just a webpage.

Comment: @Logan Murphy no my form doesn't have method="post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access $_POST["val"] unless the form you are submitting has a `method` of `post`

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">
    <input name="val"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then you can access the $_POST variable

```
echo $_POST["val"];
```

Otherwise you can set `method="get"` (or not specify the method which very likely your case) and use the $_GET variable

```
echo $_GET["val"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The registration button is not in any `form`, so clicking it does nothing.

Solution: put a `form` around the registration inputs.